# Can't access the xml node value with vbscript inside the loop

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

When I want to access the xml data with classic asp this error is seen.

My XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GenerateQRCodeWithSessionResponse xmlns="WebServices">
      <GenerateQRCodeWithSessionResult>
        <TicketDetail>
          <Code>0</Code>
          <Status>string</Status>
          <EventName>string</EventName>
          <Stadium>string</Stadium>
          <TicketNumber>123</TicketNumber>
          <TicketRate>string</TicketRate>
          <MatchName>string</MatchName>
          <MatchTime>string</MatchTime>
          <FreeTicket>boolean</FreeTicket>
          <GateNumber>string</GateNumber>
          <QRCode>string</QRCode>
          <AvailableTicket>string</AvailableTicket>
        </TicketDetail>
        <TicketDetail>
          <Code>string</Code>
          <Status>string</Status>
          <EventName>string</EventName>
          <Stadium>string</Stadium>
          <TicketNumber>string</TicketNumber>
          <TicketRate>string</TicketRate>
          <MatchName>string</MatchName>
          <MatchTime>string</MatchTime>
          <FreeTicket>boolean</FreeTicket>
          <GateNumber>string</GateNumber>
          <QRCode>string</QRCode>
          <AvailableTicket>string</AvailableTicket>
        </TicketDetail>
      </GenerateQRCodeWithSessionResult>
    </GenerateQRCodeWithSessionResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My Code:

```
SET objData = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objData.async = False
    objData.loadXML(xmldata.txt)

    Set colNodes = objData.selectNodes("//TicketDetail")
    response.write colNodes.length

    For Each objSite in colNodes
        strName = objSite.selectsinglenode ("TicketNumber").text

        response.write(strName)
    Next
```

The above code is showing

- Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
- Object required: '[object]'

This is shown by

> strName = objSite.selectsinglenode ("TicketNumber").text

Comment: `objData.load(Server.MapPath("xmldata.txt"))`

Comment: There's a space between selectsinglenode and ("TicketNumber"), which I don't think should be there.